# Is the runtime of the append procedure O(n)?

Tags: runtime, append, ocaml

For example, in OCaml when you are appending an item to a list of length n.

```
x@[mylist]
```

Comment: that depends on how the append is done. If it is a linear structure and you append to the end, then yes. If it is a append to the head of a linear structure then it is O(1), but then you have the overhead of moving N-1 nodes. If the list is linked, and the list holds references to head and tail, then it is O(1).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the runtime of `@` in OCaml is `O(n)` (where `n` is the length of the left operand).

Generally appending to the end of an immutable singly linked list (or an immutable doubly linked list for that matter) will always be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code snippet doesn't match your question, which suggests you're confused about what the operator does or which operator to use.

The `@` or [List.append](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) operator concatenates 2 lists, and `list1 @ list2` takes O(length(list1)) time and is not tail-recursive. `rev_append` is tail-recursive but still O(n) in time. The usual way to add an item to a list however is with the `::` constructor, and `item :: mylist` takes O(1) time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as mentioned, there are two reasons why it must be O(n):

1. You must iterate to the end of the singly-linked list, which takes O(n)
2. Since pairs are immutable, you must copy all the pairs in the first list in order to append, which also takes O(n)

A related interesting topic is tail-recursive vs non-tail recursive ways to append

Answer (score 1):

In summary, yes.

To illustrate, a simple (not tail-recursive) append function could be written as follows:

```
let rec (@) xs ys =
    match xs with
    | [] -> ys
    | x::xs' -> x::(xs' @ ys)
```

So internally append (`@`) breaks down the first list (`xs`) and uses `cons` (`::`) operator to build the resulting list. It's easy to see that there are n steps of prepending (`::`), where `n` is the length of the first list.